# UPDATE:Sorting a list from a for output from highest to lowest in python

Tags: python, frequency, histogram

```
    for x in letters:
         frequency[x]+=1
    for x in frequency:
        print x,frequency[x],frequency[x]/float(n)
```

Sorry but I'm fairly new to programming and everything and I'm trying to get the output to be sorted from highest value of `frequency[x]/float(n)`  to lowest value. Is there any method of being able to sort it just through the printing command?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It seems like you're using some sort of library (hist/grid/xlabel/etc) are not built into python; you're probably using something like scipy; that's probably worth mentioning in the question.

Comment: @AlexeyMK: It's `matplotlib`, and yes, it's sorely lacking context in the example. @PythonAlex: this is a very different question from your original one. Could you ask it as a separate question (and possibly remove that part from this post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
for x in sorted(frequency, key=lambda y: frequency[y]/float(n), reverse=True):
    print x,frequency[x],frequency[x]/float(n)
```

Comment: When using `sorted()`, the output only includes elements within the array. Is it possible to print other possible elements of x that aren't in a provided array?

Comment: I'll need an example of what you mean.

Comment: Well I'm trying to make a program for frequency analysis...
First it asks to import a file containing English characters only. It then converts these characters into an array where a corresponds with 0 and b with 1 and so forth... then i just basically want to count the occurences of letter x divided and print out this + the letter and the frequency. However, when i attach `sorted()`, the program dismisses any characters that are NOT in the file and only prints out characters within the file...

Comment: An example:
ABCFFGGHHH
The output would be
A 1 0.1,
B 1 0.1,
C 1 0.1,
F 2 0.2,
G 2 0.2,
H 3 0.3,

It excludes all the other characters of the alphabet... like i would like the program to print D 0 0.0, I 0 0.0 ... etc to Z 0 0.0 as well as those characters in the file...

Comment: @PythonAlex: you probably want to initialize `frequency = dict([(l, 0) for l in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'])` or something like that at the beginning of your program. You could also just iterate over the whole alphabet in your loop and use `frequency.get(x)` or `if x in frequency` to get what values are there. (Note: I'm using the actual letters, not numbers, as dict keys, but you can translate if necessary)

Answer (score 3):

For the keys:

```
sorted(frequency, key=lambda x: frequency[x], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Do you even need to divide by float(n) in the comparison? (as it's the same for all values)  I can't see any way that scaling would affect the results of a sort.

Comment: @Bwmat: Population count tends to not be negative.

Comment: i was referring to the fact that n was never defined in the actual question. We're just assuming that n = len(letters), or some other list.

Comment: Probably not an issue, but if `n` could potentially be less than zero, then it would be more efficient to use `reverse=float(n) > 0` than to divide each value by `n`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
freqs = sorted([frequency[x]/float(n) for x in frequency], reverse=True)
```

If you want it more like the print statement you have above, try this:

```
for (fxn, fx, x) in sorted([(frequency[x]/float(n), frequency[x], x) for x in frequency], reverse=True):
    print x, fx, fxn
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers flashing right before my eyes! Yes, use `sorted`. Read more [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).